# R удалить строки не соответствующие регулярке

Tags: регулярные-выражения, r

Добрый день!
Есть таблица с колонкой содержащей номера заказов или произвольные данные.
Номера заказов это число из 8 знаков начинающееся на 1 или 2. Заказов может быть несколько, указанных через запятую или пробел.
Нужно удалить все строки где находятся не номера заказов.
Как написать регулярку я представляю, вроде этого:`[12]\d{7}`

А как у удалить не соответствующие строки не знаю.

Comment: Пишешь регулярное выражение, проверяешь строку с соответствии с ним и если не совпадает то удаляеш. В чем трудности?

Comment: Не хочется использовать for и foreach, R же сам пробегает по спискам. Думаю есть простой способ не использующий циклы.

Comment: Приведите пример кода, который у вас не работает, укажите желаемый результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Чтобы исключить индексы можно использовать знак `-` (для `grep`) или `!` (для `grepl`)

2) `grep` и `grepl` имеются аргумент `invert`, который изменяет результат работы на противоположный.

RTFM, в общем.

Comment: По пункту один не понял, можно с примером кода?

Comment: `df[-index, ]` (если индекс - это числовой вектор полученный с помощью `grep`) или `df[!index, ]`  (если индекс - это логический вектор, полученный с помощью `grepl`).

Comment: df <- df[-index,] это я знал, а вот как получить вектора из grep не знаю, занимаюсь чтением мануала к grep. Но если не сложно, прошу готовый код написать.

Comment: `index <- grep(pattern, df$orders); df <- df[-index, ]`.